# Como usar dois decoradores de texto em Python?

Tags: python

Como eu posso fazer para usar dois decoradores no python, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@makebold
@makeitalic
def say():
   return "Hello"
```

que retorna:

```
<b><i>Hello</i></b>
```

Eu não estou tentando fazer o HTML assim em uma aplicação real, eu estou apenas tentando entender como decoradores e grupos de decoradores funcionam no Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta definir as funções:

```
def makebold(fn):
    def pacote():
        return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"
    return pacote

def makeitalic(fn):
    def pacote():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return pacote

@makebold
@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "Olá Mundo"

print hello() ## retorno <b><i>Olá Mundo</i></b>
```

Veja esse exemplo no [codepad](http://codepad.org/4s7s640t).

Note que é essencial usar o empacotamento ( *wrapping*) nesses delimitadores, o problema é que as pessoas em geral acreditam que os delimitadores fazem funções compostas. O que não ocorre sem esse tipo de empacotamento.

Answer (score 1):

## Definição:

Decoradores são funções retornando outra função usando a sintaxe de `@wrapper` ou empacotamento.

Como descrito na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator) decoradores não passam de açucar sintático.

Por exemplo as duas definições abaixo são equivalentes:

```
def f(...):
    ...
f = metodoestatico(f)

@metodoestatico
def f(...):
    ...
```

## Utilização

Além do próprio exemplo dado na pergunta e na resposta. É possível usar decoradores de para outros efeitos e inclusive para fazer um `debug` mais eficiente:

```
 def debugger(func):
    def f_interna(*args, **kwargs): #1
        print "Os argumentos foram: %s, %s" % (args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs) #2
    return f_interna
@debugger
def foo1(x, y=1):
    return x * y
@debugger
def foo2():
    return 2
```

**Saída**

```
>>> foo1(5, 4)
Os argumentos foram: (5, 4), {}
20
>>> foo1(1)
Os argumentos foram: (1,), {}
1
>>> foo2()
Os argumentos foram: (), {}
2
```

## Stack (ou agrupamento de decoradores)

Para utilizar-se de mais de um decorador é necessário fazer um empacotamento interno nas funções decoradoras assim como fora mostrado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29850/8917):

```
def makebold(fn):
    def pacote():
        return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"
    return pacote

def makeitalic(fn):
    def pacote():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return pacote
```